# using timer in asp.net for performing insertion to a database at a particular time

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I want to add all my contents in my tables in local database to server database at the end of day automatically.Is it possible by setting timer in login page.Or else any other way.

I am using `C#` `ASP.net 2008`,`SQL 2005`.

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1: You could create a console application that is executed with the Windows Task Scheduler at a particular time. This console will copy the data (e.g. since the last run) to the remote DB.

Idea 2: Maybe you can use SQL replication to solve it, without any custom code.

Idea 3: create a Windows-NT service that copy the local data to the remote DB.

I wouldn't use a timer within the asp.net application. This is definitely not the way to implement such things.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. What did you expect?

Comment: Can you please explain about sql replication?

Comment: I'm not a sql in depth expert.. Read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151198(v=sql.120).aspx and follow the links.. It is well documented.